# Simple MAPI generates temporary file path for jpg, png, ico files only(using "send to" --->> "Mail recipient" )

Tags: .net, windows, explorer, mapi, temporary-directory

I am using simple Mapi in VC++. 
I am calling my mail application on right click of --> "Send to" --> "Mail Recipient". 
But the issue is, assume I have selected 4 files(1st is .jpg, 2nd is .png, 3rd is .rar, 4th is .txt) of same location "E:\foldername\" and on right click --> "Send to" --> "Mail Recipient", I am getting the paths of four files but the result is unexpected.

File path for .jpg and .png is different but the names are as it is, they are like,

**C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Local\Temp**\image1.jpg

**C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Local\Temp**\image2.png

E:\foldername\file.rar

E:\foldername\txtfile.txt

Why explorer is giving me different path for jpg, png or ico files only. What is the solution of this problem? How can I get the correct path? I have used simple MAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer compress this type of files first and it stores in the temporary directory and gives path of that directory only.

Sometimes explorer gives different file name depending upon the os and office version, so at that time use filepath property and fetch filename from filepath.